# On a family of maps relating vectors to spinors, which includes a smooth map from $S^3$ to $Q^4$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, spinor

Let $Cl_n$ denotes the Clifford algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its euclidean inner product $g$, where $n \geq 3$. We use the following convention:
$$ v.w + w.v = 2g(v,w)1.$$
In particular, note that there is no minus sign on the right-hand side.
Let us assume that we have chosen a specific matrix representation of $Cl_n$.
Given $v \in S^{n-1}$, consider the $1$-eigenspace of $v$ acting on the space of spinors $S$, via the chosen representation. Let us denote this $1$-eigenspace by $\Pi_v$. I believe that $\dim(\Pi_v) = \frac{1}{2} \dim(S)$. Let us say that $\dim(S) = 2m$ (note that $\dim(S)$ is in general a power of $2$, so if $\dim(S) > 1$, which I am asssuming, since $n \geq 3$, then it must be even). We then have a map
$$f: S^{n-1} \to \operatorname{Gr}_m(S),$$
mapping $v \in S^{n-1}$ to $\Pi_v \in \operatorname{Gr}_m(S)$. I find this mapping natural.

Special cases:

1. $n = 3$. This gives a map $f: S^2 \to \mathbb{P}^1_\mathbb{C}$ which is actually a diffeomorphism. This is essentially the map which sends a vector $v \in S^2$, to its Hopf lift, which is a point in $S^3/U(1) \simeq \mathbb{P}^1$.
2. $n = 4$. This gives a map $f: S^3 \to \operatorname{Gr}_2(\mathbb{C}^4) \simeq Q^4$, where the complex $2$-Grassmannian of $\mathbb{C}^4$ is biholomorphic to a smooth complex $4$-quadric in $\mathbb{P}^5_\mathbb{C}$.

My questions are:

1. Is this mapping $f$ always a smooth embedding?
2. What are the topological properties of $f$? For instance, does $f$ always define a non-zero element in $\pi_{n-1}(\operatorname{Gr}_m(S))$?
3. Can anything interesting be said about this map $f$? (I leave this question kind of vague and open-ended).

Edit 1: the correspondence $v \mapsto \Pi_v$ reminds me of twistor theory. So this may be part of some kind of twistor correspondence for spheres. Could someone confirm if this is (as I think it is) known in the twistor theory literature perhaps?

Edit 2: regarding the link with twistor theory, the incidence relation usually considered there can be thought of as being $v.\psi = 0$. What I am considering though is different, and is of the form $v.\psi = \lVert v \rVert \psi$ (with my conventions above for the Clifford algebra).

Edit 3: the reason why I am interested in these questions is because I have defined, using this map $f$, a generalization of the Atiyah-Sutcliffe determinant, related to the Atiyah problem on configurations of points, defined on the configuration space of n distinct points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, where $d$ is not restricted to be $3$. There are also versions where $\mathbb{R}^d$ is endowed with different signatures, rather than the Euclidean one. But anyway, I think I will leave this work unpublished.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, thank you! My main interest in these maps is if they could be used for some kind of twistor correspondence between higher dimensional spheres and projectivized spinor space. The incidence relation is to be replaced with $v.\psi = \psi$. I wonder whether this has been done in the twistor literature.

Comment: Sorry for deleting my comment, I was hoping to improve the statement. What I said initially is that by the Lefschetz Hyperplane Theorem, $\pi_3(Q^4) \cong \pi_3(\mathbb{CP}^5) = 0$ so $f : S^3 \to \operatorname{Gr}_2(\mathbb{C}^4)$ is nullhomotopic.

Comment: Yes, I see. What if the dimension of the sphere is even, corresponding to $n$ being odd? But anyway, the main interest I have is the possible link with twistor theory. Thank you though, I appreciate it. I kind of suspected that somehow for $n=4$, but I wasn't a 100% sure.

Comment: I was hoping to compute the homotopy groups of $\operatorname{Gr}_m(\mathbb{C}^{2m})$, but for $m > 2$, the grassmannian isn't a complete intersection, so you'd have to use another method (maybe, using the fact that $\operatorname{Gr}_m(\mathbb{C}^{2m}) = U(2m)/(U(m)\times U(m))$).